# how to write nested JSP tag?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I write a jSP tag, like this

```
  <m:OneToOne id="12345" concept="Book">
       <m:Display>
            <m:Attribute name = "Book.BookId" /> 
            <m:Attribute name = "Book.Description" />           
       </m:Display>
    </m:OneToOne>
```

Its tag tld is:

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/JSP/TagLibraryDescriptor">
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
    <short-name>OneToOneTag</short-name>

    <tag>
        <name>OneToOne</name>
        <tag-class>com.OneToOneTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>tagdependent</body-content>

        <attribute>
            <name>id</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>

        <attribute>
            <name>concept</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>

    <tag>
        <name>Display</name>
        <tag-class>com.DisplayTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>tagdependent</body-content>
    </tag>

    <tag>
        <name>Attribute</name>
        <tag-class>com.AttributeTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
        <attribute>
            <name>name</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

Now, this code only will run the OneToOne Tag, ignore the inside tag. I realize that it is because of body-content value. but I don't know how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Does your tag code evaluate its content?

Comment: See [here](http://java.sys-con.com/node/36465), [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/taglib/handler.html), etc. Writing custom JSP tags is extremely well-documented, including those that eval their body.

Comment: How did you fix it? How did you get the inside tags evaluated?